# Server Overload Due To Log File

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

cPanel sent me the following email:

> IMPORTANT: Do not ignore this email.
>
> This is cPanel stats runner on
>   ***.***.com! While processing the log files for user ***, the cpu has been 
>   maxed out for more than a 6 hour period.
>
> The current load/uptime line
>   on the server at the time of  this
>   email is 04:41:14 up 15 days, 22:36, 0
>   users, load average: 7.66, 7.84, 8.00
>
> You should check the server to see why
>   the load is so high and take  steps to
>   lower the load. If you want stats to
>   continue to run even with a high load;
>
> Edit  /var/cpanel/cpanel.config and
>   change extracpus to a number larger
>   then 0 (run  /usr/local/cpanel/startup
>   afterwards to pickup the changes).

How can I lower the load?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how can I lower the load?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because end user shared hosting is out of scope for Server Fault

Answer (score 1):

Try running *top* and see what process is overloading the server...

Comment: /usr/sbin/clamd using using 16% of the memory. The other process is looking normal. But the other weird thing is that; clamd service is looking turn off in cPanel > Service Manager.

Answer (score 1):

That also happened to me, i ran top to view what was wrong, i noticed that Stats deamon was overloading my server, after some research i found that my access_log file was to big and log rotation deamon has not working. after fix log rotation, every thing goes fine

i know that it can be by many other reasons. i'm just telling my story.

Answer (score 0):

---

cPanel has an excellent feature which allows you, the administrator, to decide with log giles should be manipulated by cPanel's cpanellogd daemon.

This daemon will take any specified log files, compress them, and store them to /usr/local/cpanel/logs/archive/ with a file for each month. The files stored in that directory by cpanellogd are left indefinitely, meaning it is up to you to delete them.

To configure log files for manipulation by cpanellogd click on the "Server Configuration" icon from the main WHM screen.  Select the appropriate checkboxes next to the log files you would like to store indefinitely.  Then Click Save.

Copied liberally from:  http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/ServiceConfig